# Can't find Minecraft's resource pack folder or open it in minecraft itself

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I can't find the resource pack folder on my mac and when I click on the 'Open Resource Pack Folder' on Minecraft, it does nothing. Can someone help me?

Comment: I can't help but think that this is extremely easy to Google.

Answer (score 3):

Open Finder, on your keyboard press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (Or 'Go to Folder…' from the Go menu), then a popup appears.

Enter `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/resourcepacks` in the text box and press Go. Now you should be in the resourcepacks folder.

This is what the Go to Folder popup looks like:

[image]